# Using IF function in XSLT to determine if a field is blank, if so a text constant is to be added

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently I am trying to create an IF style statement using XSLT. I want the statement to read something like this:  if this field is blank or has the words 'EMPTY', then output the word 'NotDetermined'.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<FirstName>
<--I believe the IF/Test statement should start around here-->
<xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
</FirstName>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="if(normalize-space(FirstName) = '' or normalize-space(FirstName) = 'EMPTY') then 'NotDetermined' else FirstName"/>
```

or this

```
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="normalize-space(FirstName) = '' or normalize-space(FirstName) = 'EMPTY'"><xsl:text>NotDetermined</xsl:text></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: You could abbreviate the condition (in both cases) to `test="normalize-space(FirstName) = ('', 'EMPTY')"`

Comment: Note for anyone coming along later: this is XSLT 2.0